# Selecting terms from a list based on certain pattern

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following table:

```
n = 3;

myTab = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -1, n}, {j, -1, n}], 1]

(*output:
{{-1,-1},{-1,0},{-1,1},{-1,2},{-1,3},{0,-1},{0,0},{0,1},{0,2},{0,3},
{1,-1},{1,0},{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,-1},{2,0},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{3,-1},
{3,0},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}}
*)
```

Now from `myTab`, I only want to select those elements `{i,j}` that matches the pattern `{i,i+1}` or `{n,i}`. What is the best way to achieve that in Mathematica? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using patterns and [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
Cases[myTab, ({i_ ,j_} /; j == i + 1) | {n, _}]
Cases[myTab,  {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 || i == n]

(* Out:
{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3},
 {3, -1}, { 3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}} *)
```

Using [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html?q=Select) with a selector function:

```
Select[myTab, Last[#] == First[#] + 1 || First[#] == n &]

(* Same output *)
```

---

In case it helps, note also that your `myTab` can be generated directly with [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
myTab == Tuples[Range[-1, n], 2]
(* True *)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks @MarcoB

Comment: @TDH Glad it helped!

Comment: The `Tuples` code is very nice, thanks @MarcoB!

Comment: Came to the same solution: Cases[myTab, {a_, b_} /; a + 1 == b || b == n]

Comment: @Valacar Great minds think alike :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 3;
run = n - (-1) + 1; 
sel = Flatten@
   Normal@SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, {run, _} -> 1}, {run, run}];
res = Pick[myTab, sel, 1]
```

> {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3,
> 3}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list =
  {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 3}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}, 
   {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, 
   {1, 3}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, 
   {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}};

n = 3;
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{a_, b_}} /; b - a != 1 /; a != n]
```

> {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3,
> 3}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list =
  {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 3}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}, 
   {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, 
   {1, 3}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, 
   {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}};
```

---

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, Except[{n_ /; n == 3, _} | {a_, b_} /; b == a + 1]]
```

> `{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}`

Or using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, Map[MatchQ[#, {n_ /; n == 3, _} | {a_, b_} /; b == a + 1] &]@#] &@list
```

> `{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}`